# How can I catch events?

Tags: python, scripting

I used to use a script to catch events from another operator (WM_OT_event_catcher) as shown in the code below,
However, since the blender 3.3 spec change, I can no longer use it. The cause is unknown. For example, I want to know the mouse position, but it always shows 0.

Is there any other way to extract events?

```
# handle mouse events in text editor to support hover and scroll
class CE_OT_mouse_move(CodeEditorBase, Operator):
    bl_idname = "ce.mouse_move"
    bl_label = "Mouse Move"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        if getattr(context, 'edit_text', False):
            ce = get_ce(context)
            event = WM_OT_event_catcher(ce.window)
            if event:
                ce.update(context, event)


# catch the event so it can be accessed outside of operators
class WM_OT_event_catcher(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.event_catcher"
    bl_label = "Event Catcher"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    import _bpy  # use call instead of bpy.ops to reduce overhead
    call = _bpy.ops.call
    del _bpy
    
    def __new__(cls, window):
        timer(cls.call, cls.__name__, {'window': window}, {}, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        return getattr(cls, 'event', None)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        __class__.event = event
        return {'CANCELLED'}
```

**blender 3.3**

[image]

**blender 3.2**

[image]

Comment: Just asking. When you say that the cause for it not working is unknown, have you looked at what, if anything, is said in the console?

Comment: use `modal()` from `bpy.types.Opeator` class

Comment: @curious_1
This is what I believe to be the problem area after debugging on the console in my own way.
It was done on a text editor. I would present the entire code, but it is too long and I gave up.

Comment: @Karan
Thanks. I gave up and decided to handle it within INVOKE.